# posts_per_page for custom type different than selected in admin dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm new with wordpress development, I have created a film custom type like this:

```
// Create new post types, films
add_action('init', 'prowp_register_my_post_types');

function prowp_register_my_post_types(){

    $labels = array(
      'name' => 'Films',
      'singular_name' => 'Film',
      'add_new' => 'Add new film',
      'add_new_item' => 'Add New Film',
      'edit_new_item' => 'Edit Film',
      'new_item' => 'New Film',
      'all_items' => 'All Films',
      'view_item' => 'View Film',
      'search_items' => 'Search Films',
      'not_found' => 'No films found',
      'not_found_in_trash' => 'No films found in Trash',
      'parent_item_colon' => '', 
      'menu_name' => 'Films'
    );  

    $args = array(
      'labels' => $labels,
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'comprar-peliculas-80'),
      'supports' => array('title', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail'),
    );  

    register_post_type('films', $args);
}
```

And in archive-films.php I typed this:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 2,
  'paged' => $paged,
  'post_type' => 'films',
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC',
);  

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Then the page renders message "There are no entries", but if I change the attribute max number of post per page in the admin dashboard to 2, then the page returns results. The point is it, I want this type of content has 2 posts per page and the rest of the blog has 5.

How I change this attribute only for this type of content?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english ;)

Update:

In example, If:
I set in admin panel "Maximum number of entries to display in the site" to: 3
I set in archive-films.php posts_per_page => 3
I see in /films/ 3 entries and if I click in next page, I see another 3 entries in /films/page/2/

But if:
I change the value "Maximum number of entries to display in the site" to 10 in admin panel and I click in next page, 
I see in /films/page/2 message "There are not entries"

Answer (score 0):

There are no "posts_per_page" parameters for register_post_type, look there => http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

You can use filter "pre_get_posts" to filter query in admin for film.
Like that :

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'film_admin_query' );

function film_admin_query( $wp_query ) {

if( is_admin() && in_array('film',$wp_query->get('post_type'))) {
    $wp_query->set('posts_per_page',2);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but the problem is not that you can not set 3 value to post_per_page for films, but the second page does not return results if the value of post_per_page is different from that configured in the admin panel.